# Error (incompatible types) when initialising struct array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've read some similar questions to this but I still can't see where I'm going wrong.

I malloc the pointers and that seems to work OK, but I get an error (incompatible types) on this line:

```
canArray [i] = (TinCan *) malloc(sizeof(TinCan))
```

Here is the complete code:

```
typedef struct TinCan
{
    int date;
    int time;
} TinCan;

int main ()
{
    int i;
    TinCan *canArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(TinCan));

    for (i =0; i < 9; i++ )
    {
        canArray [i] = (TinCan *) malloc(sizeof(TinCan));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing that you have a `typedef struct {...} TinCan;` somewhere, then here:

```
TinCan *canArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(TinCan));
```

You have enough space for 10 `TinCan` structures, but here:

```
canArray [i] = (TinCan *) malloc(sizeof(TinCan));
```

You are trying to allocate space for another `TinCan` struct.

Do you want:

1. An array of `TinCan`s? If so, you don't need the loop - the space has already been allocated when you asked for `10 * sizeof(TinCan)`
2. An array of pointers to `TinCan` structs? If so, change the first line to:

   ```
   TinCan **canArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(canArray[0]));
   ```

   and keep the loop.

---

Some general comments:

- You don't need the cast before the `malloc()` call - see - [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- It's good practice to use `sizeof(varname[0])` rather than `sizeof(typename)`, to avoid (or make more obvious) silly mistakes.
- With the current loop code, you will leave the last `TinCan` uninitialised - you're creating 10 entries in `canArray`, but only initialising 9 of them with `i < 9`. Change that to `i < 10`, or for extra credit, swap out both for a `#define NUMBER_OF_CANS 10`

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. If I want to pass that array now to a method for initialisation, would it look like this?                           intitialise(canArray**)? It's not working for me.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can have a function initialise an array, or an array of pointers. I would probably go with the first approach (a pointer to 10 `TinCan`s), since the code will be cleaner.

Comment: Also, it's important to remember that arrays and pointers aren't the same thing - if that sounds confusing, have a read of http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html

Answer (score 3):

You have declared an array of `TinCan` structs, but your loop suggests you want an array of pointers to `TinCan` structs.

Change the declaration of canArray to:

```
TinCan *canArray[] = malloc(10 * sizeof(TinCan*));
```