# Initialising array of struct pointers causes strange error

Tags: c, arrays

I declare and try to initialise an array of struct pointers. It compiles without error, but this loop always crashes the program after 8 loops:

```
for(ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
    {
    canArray[ii]->AC = 0;
    printf("%d - AC is %d\n", ii, canArray[ii]->AC);
    }
```

Entire code here:

```
typedef struct Can
    {
    int AC;
    } Can;


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        int i, ii;

        Can **canArray= malloc(10 * sizeof(Can[0])); 

        for (i =0; i < 10; i++)
            {
            canArray[i] = (Can*) malloc(sizeof(Can));
            }

        for(ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
            {
            canArray[ii]->AC = 0;
            printf("%d - AC is %d\n", ii, canArray[ii]->AC);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Did you read and understand the answers to the previous question you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313774/error-incompatible-types-when-initialising-struct-array/16313805#16313805 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some problems with the allocating of memory.
You want to allocate space for 10 pointers of Can structure. but you do it wrong.

```
Can **canArray= malloc(10 * sizeof(Can[0]));
```

do it like this:

```
Can **canArray= malloc(10 * sizeof(Can *));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here You need to allocate space for 10 pointers of Can structure. 
For doing this You need to write

Can **canArray= malloc(10 * sizeof(Can*));

instead of `Can **canArray= malloc(10 * sizeof(Can[0]));`

Answer (score 1):

`Can` is a type, and `Can[0]` is also a type, although a bit weird: it's a *zero-length* array. This isn't actually allowed as a free-standing type, but compilers offer it as an extension.

At any rate, `sizeof(Can[0])` is just 0.

You shouldn't say the type inside `malloc`. Instead, use the variable. This eliminates redundancy. So, your code should be:

```
Can **canArray = malloc(10 * sizeof canArray[0]); 

for (size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
{
    canArray[i] = malloc(sizeof canArray[i][0]);
    canArray[i]->AC = 0;
    printf("%zu - AC is %d\n", i, canArray[i]->AC);
}
```